# How to convert one language to another language?

Tags: c#, vb.net

.NET says it supports 44 languages.for example i write the code in C# in execution time it converted in to IL and again coverted in to Machine language.is there any chance to get VB Code when iam compile the C# code.
IS THERE ANY CHANCE

Comment: it supports different languages means the il code which you get after compiling from one language can be used in other .net compliant languages

Comment: Do a web search with keyword "Reverse engineering" :)

Comment: can u elaborate ur answer please

Comment: You want to convert IL to VB.net code or the C# source file itself ?

Comment: i want to convert C#-IL-VB

Comment: It helps a lot if you have the C# source code.  Also, don't expect any converter to do a flawless job. Finally, why not just learn that other language?

Comment: Thanks for ur suggision.yesterday only i got the mail from my manager,what it contains is we got a new project that we develope in VB.thats why iam asking.

Comment: The risk of decompiling is that the resulting code won't be as easy to read as the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of free (and some not free) converters but these are mainly for C# -> VB.NET or vice versa:

http://converter.telerik.com/

http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Tangible software provide various conversions from some specified languages to others:

http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Demo.htm

There is no built in way to convert from .net language `a` to .net language `x`

Comment: hah, your typing skills beat mine!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use one of several available decompilers to decompile to VB or c# from IL. This web page lists some of them (free):
http://blog.wibeck.org/2013/02/free-options-for-reflector-net-decompiler/